# Проблема с поиском динамического поля в dataset

Tags: база-данных, delphi

Есть dataset «ibdsArchive»,
Перед открытием формы в ibdsArchive, создаю динамическое поле

```
var
  LField1: TStringField;
if FMain.ibdsArchive.FindField('NAME_PAIRS') = nil then
begin //add field 'NAME_PAIRS'
    FMain.ibdsArchive.Close;
  LField1 := TStringField.Create(FMain.ibdsArchive);
  LField1.FieldName := 'NAME_PAIRS';
  with FMain.ibdsArchive.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef do
  begin
    Name := 'NAME_PAIRS';
    DataType := ftString;
    Size := 20;
  end;
LField1.DataSet := FMain.ibdsArchive;
end;
```

поле создается, поработав, при закрытии формы хочу удалить это поле

```
var
  TC: TComponent;
…
TC := FMain.FindComponent('ibdsArchiveNAME_PAIRS');
  if TC <> nil then
  begin
    FMain.ibdsArchive.Close;
    TC.Free;
    FMain.ibdsArchive.Open;
  end;
```

но не тут то было, у меня почему-то «*ТС=nil*», хотя поле есть (в DBGrid оно отображается).

Следующий код приводит меня в некоторое смущение:

```
procedure TFGeneric.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TC: TComponent;
begin
  if FMain.ibdsArchive.FindField('NAME_PAIRS') = nil then
    showmessage('№1 NAME_PAIRS не существет')
  else showmessage('№2 NAME_PAIRS существет');

  TC := FMain.FindComponent('ibdsArchiveNAME_PAIRS');
  if TC <> nil then
    showmessage('№3 NAME_PAIRS существет')
  else showmessage('№4 NAME_PAIRS не существет');

  TC := FMain.FindComponent('ibdsArchivePAIRS_ID');
  if TC <> nil then
    showmessage('№5 PAIRS_ID существет')
  else showmessage('№6 PAIRS_ID не существет');

  showmessage('count fields: '+IntToStr(FMain.ibdsArchive.FieldCount));
  showmessage(FMain.ibdsArchive.FieldList.Text);
end;
```

- при нажатии кнопки выскакивает сообщения: №**2**, №**4**, №5 («PAIRS_ID» - это стационарное поле);
- FieldList - также выводит, в сообщении это поле.
  **Вопрос**:
  почему поле **НЕ** находит при

  **TC := FMain.FindComponent('ibdsArchiveNAME_PAIRS');**

А при FMain.ibdsArchive.FindField('NAME_PAIRS')  - находит, а также находит другие стационарные поля, типа "*ibdsArchivePAIRS_ID*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имя поля в датасете и имя компоненты на форме - разные вещи.

```
LField1 := TStringField.Create(FMain); // Owner - FMain
LField1.Name := 'ibdsArchiveNAME_PAIRS';

...

TC := FMain.FindComponent('ibdsArchiveNAME_PAIRS'); // TC - not nil
```

Comment: возможно я допустил гдето ошибку, но так тоже не находит...  <br/>     

        if FMain.ibdsArchive.FindField('NAME_PAIRS') = nil then
  begin //add field 'NAME_PAIRS'
    FMain.ibdsArchive.Close;
    LField1 := TStringField.Create(FMain);
    LField1.FieldName := 'NAME_PAIRS';
    with FMain.ibdsArchive.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef do
    begin
      Name := 'ibdsArchiveNAME_PAIRS';
      DataType := ftString;
      Size := 20;
    end;
    LField1.DataSet := FMain.ibdsArchive;
  end;

Comment: @Konstantin78 хм, Вам видна вторая строчка кода в моем ответе?

Comment: Да,  спасибо все получилось, я ее спутал с уже имеющейся - *Name := 'ibdsArchiveNAME_PAIRS';* - хотя это две разные вещи